# Python ConvNet Image Classifier - "ValueError" when fitting a model for a binary image classification

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am very new to deep learning and TensorFlow/Keras, so I'm having trouble understanding why I am throwing an error when trying to fit a model to classify images as either "dogs" or "cats." (image database can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54765). The model was written, saved, and opened in a separate module as I am learning and following a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvoLTXIjBYU). The first block of code involved creating and saving the model (with pickle), and the second block of code is the portion training the actual convolutional networks.

The image database was downloaded, saved to a file directory, and a model was written to train the classifier. The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "Pictures\\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a\\PetImages" 
#Workspace directory changed for posting
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

#Iterate between all photos of dogs and cats
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) #path to cats or dogs dir
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #Converts to grayscale, does not need color in this specific instance)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = "gray")
        break
    break

#Print image dimensions
print(img_array.shape)

#All the images are different-shaped photos, so they must be normalized
#Everything must be made the same shape
#Decide on the image size you want to go with
IMG_SIZE = 180
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

training_data = []

def create_training_data(): #With goal of iterating through everything and building the dataset
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) #path to cats or dogs dir
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #Converts to grayscale, does not need color in this specific instance)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

#Shuffle the data
import random
random.shuffle(training_data)

for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

#Packs data into variables we will use
x = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(label)
x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)


#Model was saved with pickle
import pickle
pickle_out = open("x.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(x, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

The code was then opened in another Jupyter Notebook file and used to build the CNN:

```
#Import necessary packages
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

#Load models generated in previous tutorial
x = pickle.load(open("x.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

#Normalize the data
#255 is used due to RGB imagery
x = x/255

#Model building: First layer
model = Sequential()
#Convolutional network
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
#Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

#Model building: Second layer
#Convolutional network
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
#Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

#Final output layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss= "binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer = "adam",
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 32, epochs = 3, validation_split = 0.1)
```

The exception is then thrown:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bb5f154147cd> in <module>
     39              metrics = ['accuracy'])
     40 
---> 41 model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 32, epochs = 3, validation_split = 0.1)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1038       (x, y, sample_weight), validation_data = (
   1039           data_adapter.train_validation_split(
-> 1040               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1041 
   1042     if validation_data:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in train_validation_split(arrays, validation_split)
   1374     raise ValueError(
   1375         "`validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy "
-> 1376         "arrays, found following types in the input: {}".format(unsplitable))
   1377 
   1378   if all(t is None for t in flat_arrays):

ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>
```

How can I resolve this error? It appears that the error is in the `model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 32, epochs = 3, validation_split = 0.1)` line, **because when I run the code without this line, no exceptions are thrown.** Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do transformation proccess for numpy array of y, not just X.

```py
X = []
y = []

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

print(X[0].reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1))

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)  
y = np.array(y) 

import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D


import pickle
```

.
.
.

and continue.
I have also faced the same problem but it worked after loading the data into NumPy array as I have mentioned by adding an extra row defining X and y.

Answer (score 0):

The model is expecting that the input is in the form of a numpy array. What it received is a list of integers. You will have to transform the loaded data into numpy arrays and then pass them into the model

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example as to how to do this? I’m pretty new to all of this and trying to figure it out.

Comment: I would suggest you save the training data in a numpy file https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html and load it using `numpy.load`. The same way you put `x` into a `np.array` you should `y`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 y = np.array(y)
```

In your last program after

```
 #Load models generated in previous tutorial
 x = pickle.load(open("x.pickle", "rb"))
 y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

 y = np.array(y)
```